# Typescript clutter when passing down to components

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am quite new to Typescript but wanting to understand the ins and outs a bit better.

Let's say I query or fetch some data which is returned in this form

```
{
  data: {
    edges: {
      node: {
        id: '123',
        label: 'test',
        seo: {...}
        etc...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As I pass this through to pages, components, etc., (using Nextjs) it seems that I have to ever so slightly add on to these types for each component due to destructuring and other props.

For example,

```
const Home = (props: QueryResult) => ... // QueryResult taking the shape of the above object
```

Then, in the Layout component which receives all data from `Home`:

```
const Layout = ({ children, data, isPost }: DefaultProps)
```

Another round of declarations, this time to include children & isPost. I write another interface where I reference the QueryResult from the `Home` file.

Now, Layout has a SEO component which receives `data.edges.node.seo`, with yet another type declaration to describe all Seo types, etc. I hope it's becoming clear of what I am aiming at.

Am I missing something? Is there a cleaner way to do this, for example write a bigger interface once and then borrow certain types from within that where needed?

How do you prevent having to declare and duplicate types all the time?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what you are doing as I'm not seeing a 1:1 with the example and the `Home` you mention.

If you declare types or interfaces for all data that you need to accept as a parameter or return, build your "top level" from bottom up and your child components just use the smaller type you already declared. No duplication.

```
type seoType = { /* stuff */ };
type nodeType = {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  seo: seoType;
};
type dataType = {
  edges: {
    node: nodeType;
  }
};
type topLevelType = {
  data: dataType;
}

const topLevel: topLevelType = {
  data: {
    edges: {
      node: {
        id: '123',
        label: 'test',
        seo: { /* stuff */ }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use `interface` instead of `type` based on preference or coding standards.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAzhD2AVc0C8UDeUD0AqWwArgGbFS7ZQC+A3AFCiRQB28AJhMk+hnVFAEs2ALgIAnAcwDm9fgBsAhgCMIc0TGATps2AnUIuEerQYoobBcAWGoPPlAhspEGKN79+rDqK+cUOqjoTRmhgeDAAGQgAN1UbO34LK1Ek638gujoAY3hmDSgwyJjVUUKo2Ll4zHtUt3t+R2dXao8PXzrW1qFRAHIARgAmAGYegBp6zsUVNSge4BdgMYnWuHg3HHwNEjIKamW91sD+QKogA)

Comment: Furthermore, there are tools like `json2ts` that can automatically generate these types for you from an example JSON file if you don't want to handwrite all of them. You'll usually need to do some cleanup as a result though, but it gets most of the work done.

Comment: This is really good. I'll look into it. I've googled answers for Typescript structures but was wondering what resource has helped you learn TS the best?

Comment: @Hewe I never learned JavaScript by itself until I needed to work with TypeScript, and I was coming from C++ and C#, which are strongly typed languages. So I just dove in and learned, applied, and improved as I went. I also had more than 20 years of development experience before TypeScript, which also helped. The [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system) and [The TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html) have been valuable along the way.